# Visual C++ - anonymous methods

Tags: c++, visual-c++, anonymous-function

Hi
Is there any way to use anonymous methods in Visual C++ ??

Answer (score 13):

Visual C++ 2010 supports C++0x lambda expressions,<sup>(1)</sup> which can be used as anonymous functions:

```
int i = ([](int x) { return 40 + x; })(2); // i = 42
```

<sup>(1) It's more correct to say that Visual C++ 2010 supports one of the draft specifications for C++0x lambda expressions; several relatively minor changes have been made to that draft specification since Visual C++ 2010 was released.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, C++0x will support lambdas.  In the meantime, you can use [Boost Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/lambda.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use C++0x like everyone else has suggested there are a number of ways around what you're attempting to do which mimic to some degree but do not completely capture the anonymous aspect:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& _someFunctor, double _someArgument){
    _someFunctor(_someArgument);
}
```

Or you could have a better defined structure as:

```
int bar(const boost::function<int(double,double)>& _aFunction, double arg1, double arg2){
    return _aFunction(arg1+2.0, arg2+2.0);
}
```

the [Boost::Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function.html) approach is probably the most lient as it defines a very strict function interface while allowing use with:

1. [Boost::Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html)
2. functions
3. member functions
4. functors (function like objects)

Comment: boost::function is not better defined than the template solution. The template is compile-time, boost::function is run-time. They're two different solutions to two different problems.

Comment: @DeadMG it will not properly compile if the object passed to the function does not match or is not implicitly convertible to that defined in the code.  That's compile time to me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean C++/CLI, anonymous methods is a C# term.  No, not supported.  It doesn't support the C++0x lambdas either.

Comment: It does support lambda expressions in MSVC10.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Only for native C++, though.  TTo the best of my knowledge, the C++/CLI compiler doesn't support C++0x lambdas.  The question wasn't originally tagged [c++]; I added that based on the text; perhaps the OP did mean C++/CLI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C++0x allows lambda functions.